# grunt-tslint is not working at the watch task

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, tslint, grunt-ts

I'm working on an angular2 project and have included grunt-tslint to improve my code. The grunt task "tslint" and default grunt task is workink fine but when I include it to the watch task it's not linting. I tried to delete every other watch task but also not working.

This are my versions:
grunt: v1.0.1
grunt-contrib-watch: 1.0.0
grunt-ts: v6.0.0-beta.3
grunt-tslint: 4.0.0

And the grunt tasks:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    tslint: {
        options: {
            configuration: "tslint.json",
            force: false,
            fix: false
        },
        files: {
            src: ['app/**/*.ts']
        }
    },
    ts: {
        default : {
            src: ['app/**/*.ts'],
            outDir: 'outDir/app/',
            tsconfig: './tsconfig.json'
        }
    },

watch: {
        tslint: {
            files: ['app/**/*.ts'],
            task: ['tslint']
        },
        ts: {
            files: ['app/**/*.ts'],
            tasks: ['ts']
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ts');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-tslint');

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'ts', 'tslint'
]);

grunt.registerTask('validate:ts', ['tslint']);
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

**UPDATE:**

Try replacing your watch task with the following instead:

```js
watch: {
    ts: {
        files: ['app/**/*.ts'],
        tasks: ['tslint', 'ts']
    }
}
```

**Note:**

1. The [target](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) named `tslint` has been deleted from your `watch` task.
2. The call to run the `tslint` task has now been added to the `tasks` array of the `ts` target.

Now when you run **`$ grunt watch`** the files will be:

1. Linted using `tslint` according to the rules defined in `tslint.json`.
2. If they PASS that check they will be transpiled with `grunt-ts`.
3. If they FAIL that check no files will be transpiled, and any errors will be reported to the CLI.

Hope this helps!

---

**PREVIOUS ANSWER:**

One potential solution is to try reverting to the last stable version of the `grunt-ts` package.

To do this:

1. `cd` to your project directory.
2. Uninstall the current version of `grunt-ts`:

`$ npm uninstall grunt-ts --save-dev`

3. Then install the last stable release of `grunt-ts` *(which appears to be [5.5.1](https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts/releases))*

`$ npm install grunt-ts@5.5.1 --save-dev`

**NOTE:** I recommend trying the above with a **copy** of your project directory to see whether its successful !

Comment: thanks for your hint. I try it but it is still not working. But I think it's better to use the stabel version in the end and I "updated" it to v5.5.1

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution.
The watch task was watching the folder with two task (ts and tslint) and it was only runing ts (the last task). I combined both and now it's working:

```
        ts: {
            files: ['app/**/*.ts'],
            tasks: ['ts', 'tslint']
        }
```

Comment: Hah - I was just updating the previous post with the same answer.

Comment: Hihi, great. Thank you very much for the support